# Why do we need Lambda in between API Gateway and Dynamo DB in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I am building a service using AWS. My use case is a simple CRUD operation, of a product configuration, on Dynamo DB using API's.

**Approach 1:** I was initially thinking to design it using API Gateway, Lambda and DynamoDB.

**Approach 2:** One of my peers asked me to directly integrate API Gateway with DynamoDB.

In my understanding, as of now, using Lambda as a middle layer will help me better to deliver customized responses and also would do some extra error validation (like bad keys supplied by user) in addition to API Gateway. But I am still not very much convinced to go by approach 1 or 2.

I was wondering if anyone could help me elaborate some pros and cons of approach 2 in relation to approach 1. Any help would be much appreciated.

My product configuration is a bunch of 15 key value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if anyone could help me elaborate some pros and cons of approach 2 in relation to approach 1.

There could be **several pros and cons**. Example of a positive is that you pay only for API Gateway and DynamoDb - not for lambda invocations. Example of a negative is is that an initial setup and maintainability of API->DynamoDB can be more complex and tiresome then when using API->Lambda->DynamoDb.

However, one drawback of the first approach that can be important in may use cases is time efficiency. Lambda function is known to suffer from so called, **cold start latency** (more and how to deal with this is [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-for-aws-lambda-predictable-start-up-times-with-provisioned-concurrency/) - Provisioned Concurrency). Subsequently, in Approach 1 with lambda, you may find that the cold start is a troublesome, especially for in-frequently used APIs. In contrast, in the Approach 2, you have **direct connection** between API and DynamoDB and don't have to worry about any delays caused by intermediates between API gateway and DynamoDB.